# How to load geojson file as a Tile Layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to load the big GeoJSON file using the OpenLayers. The problem is after loading it then the complete map becomes slow to do any other operation. So my question is there anyway to load a geojson file as a Tile rather ?

Here is my code:

```
function addGEOJSONLayer() {
                console.log("reached");
                var url= 'http://172.61.25.51:8080/test/ab.json';
            
            var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
              strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
              projection: 'EPSG:4326',
              loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
                $.ajax(url).then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response);
                  vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
                });
              }
            });


            var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: vectorSource,
                style: function (feature, resolution) {
                    return [new ol.style.Style({
                          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            width: 1,
                            color: feature.get('stroke')
                        }),
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: feature.get('fill'),
                        })
                    })];
                  }
            });
            var ext = vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent();
            map.getView().fit(ext, map.getSize());
            map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
        }
```

Any suggestions will be of great help! Thanks

Comment: what data does the GeoJSON file contain? If it is "official data" maybe the provider of the data provides also a WM(T)S. If it is your data you would have to create your own WM(T)S server and access the data from there

Comment: It contains official data.and I was thinking if its there any way i upload my geojson data in GeoServer then it might be useful

Comment: You could use geojson-vt https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson-vt.html